# Keep scale on windows resize CorePlot 2.0 Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, core-plot

Have been looking for the opposit to scaleToFit. I would like to keep the horizontal scale when the windows is resized?

Is the any setting or do I have to re-calculate the x-axis scale manually based on the size of the window when it's resized?

I would appreciate any hints or ideas. Thanks in advance!

Regards, Jan

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the Core Plot hosting view a fixed size and place it inside another view that tracks changes in the in the window size. This would clip the edges of the graph inside the parent view. If that won't work, you'll need to track changes to the size and update the plot ranges yourself.